# Iterate and plot columns in pandas dataframe with increasing column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe of 21 rows x 3000 columns. The columns names are like:

```
X_0  X_1  X_2  X_3 ... X_1000  
Y_1  Y_2  Y_3  Y_4 ... Y_1000 
Z_0  Z_1  Z_2  Z_3 ... Z_1000
```

What I am trying to do is to plot all 21 rows of X_0 vs Y_0 and then X_1 vs Y_1 and so one.

I have not been able to find any examples of this or if it is even possible

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On the same plot??? (provide a minimal reproducible example of your dataframe)

Comment: You want X_i vs Y_i, X_i vs Z_i, and Y_i vs Z_i for all 0<=i<=1000? 3000 lines on one scatterplot? 3000 different scatterplots?

Comment: Are your X_i/Y_i/Z_i values representing spatial coordinates?

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you want to make 21 line plots with the x columns representing the x-coordinates and the y columns representing the y coordinates. I'm going to generate my own set of random data to demonstrate the script.

```
# Random data
xyz = np.random.randint(0, 100, (21, 3003))
df = pd.DataFrame(xyz).rename(columns = {i: f'x_{i}' if i <= 1000 else f'y_{i-1001}' if i <= 2001 else f'z_{i-2002}' for i in range(3003)})

# Plotting begins here
plt.figure()

for row in range(21):
    x, y = [[df.at[row, f'{x}_{i}'] for i in range(1001)] for x in ['x', 'y']]
    plt.plot(x, y)
```